# Flutter - How to place dynamic tiles and wrap to next row based on parent width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve the following design where the list will be dynamic.

[image]

Thought of using column & row with some calculation but honestly right now I am clueless. Any ideas, any suggestions, any references would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **Wrap** widget, like this:

```
              Wrap(
                    spacing: 10,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MyContainerWidget('Text1'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text2'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text-text-3'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text-text-4'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text-text-5'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text6'),
                      MyContainerWidget('Text7'),
                    ],
                  ),
```

and create custom widget **MyContainerWidget** like this:

```
class MyContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  MyContainerWidget(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[700])),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use **for** loop in **Wrap** Widget

```
          Wrap(
                spacing: 10,
                children: <Widget>[
                   for(var item in _myListStrings)
                      MyContainerWidget(item),
                ],
              ),
```

**_myListStrings** is List of String